# Angularjs and jquery html5Loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my app i try to create a preloader with [jquery.html5loader](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jquery.html5loader) like this :

```
    $.html5Loader({
  filesToLoad:    'load.json', // this could be a JSON or simply a javascript object
  onBeforeLoad:       function () {

    $('body').append('<div id="load">Loading....</div>');
  },
  onComplete:         function () {
    $('#load').hide();
    console.log('Complete Loaded');
  },
  onElementLoaded:    function ( obj, elm) { },
  onUpdate:           function ( percentage ) {
    // sleep(100000);
    console.log(percentage);
    $("#load").text('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+percentage);
  }
});
```

the script correctly work and i get `Complete loaded` log in console when all script loaded but i get another error on angular

> Uncaught object angular.js:36

in my json file i load all script except `jquery,angular.js,angular-route.js` . i think the problem is because i have a this code in my html :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing something wrong. I've created [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/jMLpe/) embedding angularjs in the page and everything seems to work.

```
$.html5Loader({
  filesToLoad: {
    files: [{
      "type": "SCRIPT",
      "source": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js",
      "size": 4.096,
    }]
  },
  onBeforeLoad: function() {
    console.log('Before load');
    $('body').append('<div id="load">Loading....</div>');
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    $('#load').hide();
    console.log('Complete Loaded');

  },
  onUpdate: function(percentage) {
    // sleep(100000);
    console.log(percentage);
    $("#load").text('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + percentage);
  }
});
```